# html.ActionLink(): ViewController stops working if class Attribute is added

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I encountered a very weird behaviour in my project today. 
So I am working on a website which has an admin view an a common user view. The pages are stored in a folder named "Admin" and a folder named "User" under the folder "Views"

I started only setting up functionality for the Admin pages, so I never realized that my UserController didn't work. It always routed me to **Admin/Somepage** instead of User/Somepage.

After some testing I found the following problem:

If I use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "AdminHome", "Admin")
@Html.ActionLink("User", "UserHome", "User")
```

everything works just fine.

But as soon as I add a class to the link for example

```
@Html.ActionLink("User", "UserHome", "User", new { class= "someClass" })
```

it stops working. When I now click on the Link to the user homepage it routes to **Admin/UserHome** instead of **User/UserHome** and obviously can't find the page.

Why is that? Anyone ever experienced this?

I mean I can still wrap it in another div and add the class there. I just want to know if there is a reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: What happens if you use `new { @class= "someClass" }`? Notice that `class` is a reserved keyword so you need to escape it with a prefix `@`

Comment: Because it needs to be `@Html.ActionLink("User", "UserHome", "User", null, new { class= "someClass" })`

Comment: Then maybe a mix of the two above comments: `@Html.ActionLink("User", "UserHome", "User", null, new { @class= "someClass" })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload. By using this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User", "UserHome", "User", new { class= "someClass" })
```

ASP.Net MVC thinks that the [the fourth parameter is route values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx) which is not the case.

To make it work as expected you need to use [this overload that takes five parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx) and set the attributes at the fifth position like below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User", "UserHome", "User", null, new { class= "someClass" })
```

I set `null` at the fourth parameter because it seems like that your controller action doesn't need any route value.

Comment: Any reason why you linked the same link twice?

Comment: @Rafalon My bad. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. However, please re-read the parts *fourth parameter* (first overload) and *five parameters* (second overload). It seems that you count `this` for the first overload, and you don't count it for the second. Or am I counting wrong?

Comment: Thank you! So bad that didn't realize my mistake. I thought cause the class Element is working and the AdminController works too the code should be fine. Missed that there is another parameter in between.

Answer (score 3):

Because as Stephen Muecke pointed out in his comment, the method you should be using is [`ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd505040(v=vs.118)#linkextensionsactionlink-method-htmlhelperstringstringstringobjectobject) with the following signature:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)

@Html.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes)
```

where you currently are using [`ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd505040(v=vs.118)#linkextensionsactionlink-method-htmlhelperstringstringobjectobject) with following signature:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    object routeValues, // here you passed controllerName ("User") instead
    object htmlAttributes
)

@Html.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, routeValues, htmlAttributes)
```